# Parse Firebase Dynamic Link for Password Reset IOS

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

My issue is that I’m trying to parse my deep link for information to then change a users password. When I send the password reset email I included the users email address within the deep link parameter, however is there a specific way to parse this using FDL library once the link is opened in app? For security purposes there must be a way to verify the generated action code in the deep link to verify the link is legitimate aswell? I know that the fire base docs touch on this for web applications, but it doesn’t go into specifics for IOS.

Best,
James